dead keys in wine due to my keyboard layout
I am using Ubuntu 23.10 and have a few games running through wine. These work perfectly other than some keys not being recognized from my keyboard. These are French characters like é, ç, à, ...
Only games ran via wine/steam do not respond to me pressing these characters. (Does the Ubuntu version of steam even use wine? I assume so.) In Ubuntu itself I am having zero issues; this is a wine exclusive issue.
When Googling this, I have found several people with similar issues and the issue appears to be your locale. I have tried changing this with some success using the update-locale command. It changed some of the language on my system (which I really don't want) but if I use the locale command to check, it actually doesn't actually change anything there so I'm not even sure if I did it correctly.
But like I said, I don't want to change the language of my Ubuntu as everything on my system is exactly how I want it to be. It's wine that's having the issues. I did find the following command to start an application in wine with a different locale which others said worked for them:
LC_ALL=fr_BE.utf8 wine C:/Games/Homecoming/bin/win64/launcher.exe

But this returns the follow error:
03b0:fixme:heap:GetNumaHighestNodeNumber semi-stub: 00007FFFFE1FFA90

Not sure if I'm on the right track with this one. Am I even right in assuming the locale is the issue here? How can I solve this without changing anything about my system. The only thing I had to do is pick the correct keyboard layout in the system settings for Ubuntu to work correctly.

I have solved the issue after a lot of trial and error. I stumbled on this bug report from Wine which is very similar to my issue:
https://bugs.winehq.org/show_bug.cgi?id=30984
I noticed the status of this report was "staged" and after looking this up I learned that a lot of bug fixes are apparently on the staged branch of Wine so I downloaded this with the following command:
sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-staging

This solved the issue.
